# Probability of A winning a 3 points game if A has already won 2 of 3 points

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A and B having equal skill, are playing a game of three points. After A has won 2 points and B has won 1 point, what is the probability that A will win the game?

I tried to solve the above problem using a counting diagram given below.

Given that A has already two of the first three points, the diagram below shows all cases for A to be a winner. A can win in 6 different ways if A has 2 of 3 points already. We don't need to play the 5th point if A has already won in 4th point, which is considered in the diagram.

Also, total number of cases is 9. So, probability that A will win given the pre- condition is 6/9 = 2/3.

I am not sure if my counting diagram is incomplete. It seems ok to me.

The answer given in the book is 3/4.
[image: Counting diagram for this problem]

Comment: Hint:  Either $A$ wins on the next round or we advance to $(2,2)$ in which case the probability is clearly $\frac 12$.

Comment: Should say:  I really can't follow what you wrote.  Given that we are in the state $(2,1)$ there are at most two games left to be played.

Comment: I have shown that in the diagram

Comment: And $\frac 12+\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 34$.

Comment: I think you are trying to say something like:  "From the state $(2,1)$ there are three possible paths, namely $A$, $BA$, and $BB$.  Since $A$ wins in two of those the answer is $\frac 23$."  The problem, however, is that those three paths are not equally probable.  $A$ occurs with probability $\frac 12$, the other two with probability $\frac 14$ each.  I don't understand why your tree is so complicated though.  The history of games that lead us to $(2,1)$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Your nine cases don't have equal probability, so you can't just use the count directly.

Comment: If we are in state (2,1) then we could have AAB or ABA or BAA as possible outcomes initially, yo start with. I then expand this initial state to the next level of (3,1) or (2,2). If it's (2,2) then I expand one more level so it's (3,2). That is what I have shown in my diagram listing possible outcomes.

Comment: I see, so a tree needs to have equally likely paths for a tree to be used. I wasn't aware of this fact.

Comment: @lulu, so we don't need to bother how we reached the initial state because we know that state has definitely occurred. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Including the entire history just confuses the matter.  In different situations, there might be infinitely many paths that lead to a given state, for example.

Comment: @lulu, I was listing all possible paths since I thought it was a problem on conditional probability. If you like, please post the solution as you have mentioned so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: It is a matter of conditional probability.  The condition being that we are in the state $(2,1)$.  If you like, you can post your own solution which people here can review.

Comment: @lulu, but the condition is occurring with a probability of 1 since it's certain to have occurred.

Comment: In any conditional probability we are assuming the condition to hold.  That is not the same as saying that condition had a probability $1$ of being reached.  Here, since we are assuming that the condition has been reached, we can simply consider possible paths going forward.

Comment: @lulu, I get it now. Probability is quite a complex topic for beginners. Thanks for your explanations.